# Multiple [Personality] Accounts

Tags: discussion

I searched and found nothing at all, not just nothing useful but actually nothing at all.

Is it possible to have stack overflow network account and user profile page in general not show specific SO sites?

I know, I could just have 2 accounts. I already have 2 accounts, but that's not what I'm wanting. What I want is to hide my paper trial without shredding the papers.

Here's my thinking....So I work for a company and as it turns out my supervisors are very religious and very outspoken about this and just for some salt they're very fundamentalist. Me personally, I don't mind them at all and for the most part we get along well enough.

Well, here's my issue, they know I'm on SO and have checked my profile. In fact they review it every time I come up for reviews. No big deal, I'm fairly proud of the answers I've given and not at all ashamed of my questions....but there it is, a link to one of the science based sites....so they go snooping and find I'm a regular science defending geek. Well, here it comes, the unwanted questions. The spur of the moment debates. The looks. Suddenly everything is my fault.

Well, I'm finding a new job now, but live and learn and prevent it from happening again. Is there a way or could that be a feature suggested to optionally list/exclude which sites are linked to my profile /network profile.

And before you say that never happens, its happened to me 3 times now (not SO fault, boss just found out what I believed and I went from being the star employee to suddenly everything was my fault) And sadly it does happen a lot more than I thought. I can't prove anything but I can at least try to reduce the chance of it happening again...but I want to contribute to all the sites under the same name. I just don't want my profile to show my association to certain sites.

Comment: You can hide your communities in the edit profile page.

Comment: @TinyGiant Wow, I've looked, and in that very area and never saw that before. Well, thanks then.

Comment: Note that it only hides the site in the list of sites in your profile on various sites in the network. It doesn't hide the sites in your user page on stackexchange.com

Comment: @nhahtdh That's good to know, but from what I understand, most people don't even know about stackexchange itself: )